# Can I merge Sharepoint lists with unique value conflicts by updating metadata?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to merge or copy data from either an excel spreadsheet or another sharepoint list into a master list.  The main "item number" column will enforce unique values, but each item will be assigned to multiple "project numbers" using metadata.

Is it possible to tell sharepoint to auto-update the metadata when duplicate items are added to the list?  I could probably even edit the metadata manually if it would display the old entry for modification, but the only option I've seen is modify or delete the new item.

Comment: You should be more specific with your question. Typically, the questions that get the best answers provide what they have tried, maybe some code if needed, and a detailed explanation of the question. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask questions!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me(from the description you have given) you are trying to collate several lists in to one and any data within each list you need to merge. Is this correct?

If so you will probably need to do a bit of custom code. Heres a little run through.

Get the list objects of the lists containing your items or grab your items from excel.

Iterate through each of the items in the list(or excel) importing the items over to the Master list.

Just before the above step you will need to check if the unique identifier already exists in the master list. If it does grab that item and update it if it doesn't continue adding the item as normal.

As always i would recommend you have a crack at it yourself. It's far more rewarding to make something work yourself and to be honest to do the above if you can read other peoples code it should take too long to copy(i mean reuse :P) other peoples code off the web to get the desired outcome.

I am not aware of a way you would be able to do this out of the box or via SharePoint designer.

Hope this helps

Truez

Comment: Close.  Basically all I need to do is be able to update one cell with some kind of grouping tag for each unique item number. Let me see if I can break this down.  I will have a master list of part numbers with a couple columns of supporting data. That data does shouldn't have to change because it's unique to each part. But, sometimes a single part is used in mulitple projects, so I want to assign multiple project identifiers to some of the part numbers.  I think that will allow me to create a custom view per project to filter out all of it's parts. Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like you have a good base to get rolling with. Best thing to do is start off small and then grow bigger. So if you have never updated or copied a list item this should be your first step. :) good luck and if i can help i will

Comment: Also, from there... I will probably be importing new projects with 50-60 items a couple times a week.  At first, the number of duplicates will be small, but as I build the list, I can see up to 75% or more of the items being duplicates.  This is why I'd like to update some kind of project tag as simply as possible. Is this even a reasonable use for this software or should I try something else?

Comment: Thanks, I think we doubled there.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I don't see why not. dependent on processing you might want to move this in to a timer job so it runs overnight. This is only something that will come apparant once you have your logic fully thought through. I would suggest the event receiver is still a good bet then see how performance is affected. As i do not fully understand what your aim is this is a decision best made by you. What you have to remember is that if the item is a duplicate then you will beed to do something to it which takes processin. Questions you need to ask are does the data have to be processed instantly or can it wait